# How do I view an XML file in browser using Codeigniter

Tags: php, xml, codeigniter

Ok, I have looked around, and I can't seem to figure this out.

Here is my CodeIgniter Structure:

- orders

  - application

    - controller
    - model
    - view
  - xml

As you can see, the XML folder is outside the application folder. 
Inside the XML folder I have an xml file named example.xml.
Inside the controller, how do I load the xml file to view it in the browser?

```
class Example extends CI_Controller {
   public function view_xml(){
       header("Content-type: text/xml");
       $this->load->view() ??????? // Here is where I'm stuck
   }
}
```

I have tried using BASEPATH and $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] but with no luck.
I want to be able to type in the url example/view_xml to view the xml in the browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Never mind, I figured it out. Instead of using CodeIgniter's $this->load->view(), I just load the file and echoed it out to the screen.

```
public function view_xml(){
   header("Content-type: text/xml");
   $xml_file = file_get_contents($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/xml/example.xml");
   echo $xml_file;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot view directly the .xml file, you need to prase it is a database file just like JSON.

Below is an .xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<note>
<to>Tove</to>
<from>Jani</from>
<heading>Reminder</heading>
<body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
```

We want to output the element names and data from the XML file above.
Here's what to do:

1. Load the XML file
2. Get the name of the first element
3. Create a loop that will trigger on each child node, using the
   children() function
4. Output the element name and data for each child node

Example:

```
<?php
$xml = simplexml_load_file("test.xml");

echo $xml->getName() . "<br />";

foreach($xml->children() as $child)
  {
  echo $child->getName() . ": " . $child . "<br />";
  }
?>
```

The result:

```
note
to: Tove
from: Jani
heading: Reminder
body: Don't forget me this weekend!
```

Comment: Really, there is no way for me to view an XML in the browser? I'm not looking to parse the XML, but I need to show the tags as well. I mean, I can do something like this $output = "<root><name>sample_name</name></root>"; print($output); and it is fine, but loading a file with XML data isn't working at all.

Comment: you want to open the xml just the text contents of it?